# How can I SSH into a Redhat EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, redhat

I've read [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html) which says I should use:

> ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem
> my-instance-user-name@my-instance-public-dns-name

but I have no idea what `my-instance-user-name` should be.

---

For Ubuntu I always do

> ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem **ubuntu**@my-instance-public-dns-name

after changing permissions of my key via `chmod 400 /path/my-key-pair.pem`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Redhat (RHEL) [it will be](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/tutorials-wordpress-launch-instance.html) `ec2-user`. For other OS, the list is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html):

> - For Amazon Linux 2 or the Amazon Linux AMI, the user name is ec2-user.
> - For a CentOS AMI, the user name is centos or ec2-user.
> - For a Debian AMI, the user name is admin.
> - For a Fedora AMI, the user name is fedora or ec2-user.
> - For a RHEL AMI, the user name is ec2-user or root.
> - For a SUSE AMI, the user name is ec2-user or root.
> - For an Ubuntu AMI, the user name is ubuntu.
> - For an Oracle AMI, the user name is ec2-user.
> - For a Bitnami AMI, the user name is bitnami.
> - Otherwise, check with the AMI provider.